# How to align list side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have to two list. I want to display them in side by side like this

> A  C
>
> B  D

A and B  are in same list as well as C and D are in same list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/K3xcg/)

This will help you

```
<ul style="width:10%; float:left;">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
   </ul>

   <ul style="width:10%; float:left;">
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
   </ul>
```

Thanks....

Comment: Would be better if you could post the code in the answer instead of just a link (links go dead and people trying to find solutions later can't make use of the posts).

Comment: But now its active. So thats its ok :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use to ul and make them float:left;

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul
{
float:left;
margin:0 5px;
}
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K3xcg/39/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> ```
> <ul class="first">
>       <li>1</li>
>       <li>2</li>
>   </ul>
>
>
> <ul class="second">
>       <li>3</li>
>       <li>4</li>
>   </ul>
> ```

css

> ```
>    ul.first{ position:fixed; float:left}
>
>       ul.second{ position:fixed; float:right}
> ```